# What is the correct service definition for a Bluetooth LE (Smart) Coffee maker?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, .net-gadgeteer

I want to build an IOT (Internet of things) device using the Bluetooth Smart protocol / GATT.  I'm a bit confused how I'd make this [conform with the BLE specs.](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/Pages/Definition-Browser.aspx?_ga=1.226995931.774682357.1442074132)  All the profiles listed seem to focus on health-stuff and I'm having trouble making the conceptual leap to other applications.

Assume this device is a coffee maker, and I want to :

- Get an alert when the water / coffee needs a refill
- Set a timer for when to make coffee
- Recognize my coffee preference vs my wife's
- Send arbitrary text to be displayed on the LED

**Question**

1. What are the appropriate Charactertistics, Services, and Profiles I should use?
2. Do I need to register these profiles, or UIDs anywhere (e.g. Bluetooth.org)
3. Where do I enable security? (I don't want anyone to know I put lots of sugar in my coffee?
4. Where do I send my custom text? In a custom structure?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to search for the customized profile (including all services and characteristics) of your specific coffee maker. There isn't a predesigned profile.
2. No, you don't need to register the profile with it's UUID's. It is already used from your coffee maker ;)
3. This should be the last point of your work and depend on your manager device.
4. You have to send your data to the right characteristics which depend on the customized profile of your coffee maker.